# How to convert a General format cell to h:mm:ss in R?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am trying to convert a column in a `CSV` file from `General` format to `h:mm:ss` inside of R.

Inside of Excel, I ran the function, `=CELL("format", cell)` and it returned: `G` which corresponds to the `General` format.  If I want to do it in Excel, I would change the format and it would be `D8` which is `h:mm:ss`.

I am trying to do this conversion in R, as opposed to making the conversion inside of Excel.

When my `CSV` file is uploaded into `R`, the format of the Time column is `factor`.

When I run:

```
uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))
uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile1$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The class of the Time column is returned as: `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

But, when I go to try and graph it using `Dygraph`, the Error is that it `cannot calculate the periodicity of 1 observation`.

But here is where I get confused:
When I manually change the Format inside of Excel, the class of the Time column when I upload the file is also `factor` and is also `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` after I run the two lines of code.

The csv file is found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzg7bDcyZobbc1Zoc0VoN3ZzSmM/view?usp=sharing

## ui.R

```
library(xts)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Data Graph",
tabPanel("Upload a CSV File:",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels1", label = "Choose a Temp. Rise Location",
                                      choices = NULL),
                          fileInput('file2', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels2", label = "Choose a Temp. Rise Location",
                                      choices = NULL),
                          tags$hr(),
                          checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                       c(Comma=',',
                                         Semicolon=';',
                                         Tab='\t'),
                                       ',')

                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                              dygraphOutput('graph')
                        ))



                        )

                               )))
```

## server.R

```
observeEvent(uploadedFile1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels1', choices = names(uploadedFile1))
  })
  observeEvent(uploadedFile2, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels2', choices = names(uploadedFile2))
  })
uploadedFile1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file1, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file1)) return(NULL)"

     uf1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  })
observeEvent(uploadedFile1(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels1', choices = names(uploadedFile1()))
  })
  observeEvent(uploadedFile2(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels2', choices = names(uploadedFile2()))
  })

  output$graph <- renderDygraph({

    # Clean up the loaded CSV File, convert Time column to a Time Object for Dygraph.
    uploadedFile1 <- uploadedFile1()
    uploadedFile2 <- uploadedFile2()

    uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))
    uploadedFile2$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile2$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))

    uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile1$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    uploadedFile2$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile2$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

  uploadedFile2 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file2, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file2)) return(NULL)"
selectedInput1 <- input$uploadChannels1
    selectedInput2 <- input$uploadChannels2
    component5 <- uploadedFile1[, selectedInput1]
    component6 <- uploadedFile2[, selectedInput2]
    cbinded <- cbind(component5, component6)

        xts(cbinded, uploadedFile1$Time, uploadedFile2$Time)  %>% 
      dygraph()

    })

})

     uf2 <- read.csv(input$file2$datapath, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  })
```

Comment: `cannot calculate the periodicity of 1 observation` is not due to the class of your column.

Comment: But I do not receive the error when I am using the pre-formatted (formatted inside of Excel) CSV file.

Comment: The time is being read in as `h:mm.s` instead of `h:mm:s`.  Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes, if you change your time format to h:mm.s in the code it should function correctly. Unless you have a way to fix it in all the csv files you intend to work with.

Comment: When I change: `uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))` to `uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M.%S"))`, I get the error that it cannot calculate periodicity of 1 observation.